# Generate Java Heap Dump on uncaught Exception

Tags: java, jvm, heap-dump

I try to generate a Heap Dump when a uncaught exception is fired. I tried using jmap, but because the process is finished when the exception happens this is not possible.

Using a UncaughtExceptionHandler is no option either, because I only have the binaries of the programs that is executed.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT: It is important that the technique is available through a command line or similar, because I need to automated this. Using a GUI is no option

Comment: Uncaught in the sense of "causing the program to crash".

Comment: @assylias This generates Thread dumps of the stack. I want the heap dump

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved with [JVMTI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html) agent that will listen to [VMDeath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#VMDeath) event and then use [JMM interface](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/services/jmm.h) to initiate Heap Dump.

Here is a sample source code of such JVMTI agent:

```
#include <jvmti.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "jmm.h"

JNIEXPORT void* JNICALL JVM_GetManagement(jint version);

void JNICALL VMDeath(jvmtiEnv* jvmti, JNIEnv* jni) {
    JmmInterface* jmm = (JmmInterface*) JVM_GetManagement(JMM_VERSION_1_0);
    if (jmm == NULL) {
        printf("Sorry, JMM is not supported\n");
    } else {
        jstring path = (*jni)->NewStringUTF(jni, "dump.hprof");
        jmm->DumpHeap0(jni, path, JNI_TRUE);
        printf("Heap dumped\n");
    }
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, char* options, void* reserved) {
    jvmtiEnv* jvmti;
    (*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void**)&jvmti, JVMTI_VERSION_1_0);

    jvmtiEventCallbacks callbacks;
    memset(&callbacks, 0, sizeof(callbacks));
    callbacks.VMDeath = VMDeath;
    (*jvmti)->SetEventCallbacks(jvmti, &callbacks, sizeof(callbacks));
    (*jvmti)->SetEventNotificationMode(jvmti, JVMTI_ENABLE, JVMTI_EVENT_VM_DEATH, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

After you've compiled it into the shared library (libdump.so) run Java with `-agentpath` option:

```
java -agentpath:/path/to/libdump.so MainClass
```

If you wish to handle uncaught exceptions instead of waiting for VMDeath, you may use similar technique to install callback for Exception event. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23567931/3448419) for an example.

Comment: While maybe not exactly what the OP wanted, this is an awesome answer.

Comment: I found out that to compile the example above it is necessary to link it against jvm.dll/libjvm.so

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your processing into a deamon thread. this way you can access it with memory analysis tools. JVisualVM is a JDK tool you can find it in your JAVA_HOME\bin.

There are also another way, called dump analyser. You run your application with these JVM parameters :

- -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
- -XX:HeapDumpPath="your_path"

But this is used only if you have an OutOfMemoryError. Try to find if it's possible to generate the dump for any performance.

Another good eclipse based tool is [MemoryAnalyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest [Java Visual VM](http://visualvm.java.net/). It can connect dynamically. I found it useful. You might want to give a try.

Comment: This looks useful, but has it a cli? I need to integrate this in a system to automatically explore heap dumps

Comment: Yes it does. go ahead and use it.

Comment: Could you tell me where to find more informations about this? I can't find anything. Just stuff with the GUI