# capture JVM snapshot at every error and exception

Tags: java, logging, error-handling, jvm, snapshot

I am looking into Tapiki https://www.takipi.com/product. For every error and exception they add an url. In the url, they show what is the value of every variable at that point of error.

I am guessing that they use JVM snapshots for that purpose. How is it possible to capture JVM snapshot at the time of error and map it to code?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily handle `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` heap dumps by using `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemory` command line option (see [command line tools reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html))

For all other cases you should use [JVMTI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html) and implement your own agent for exception interception. You can find example program [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23640439/1545775)